# UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I had a question regarding `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

I have a grid view controller and I have  put a breakpoint in the autorotate method it see if the method was being called. Turns out, even if I rotate the device (testing on simulator), the method is not being called.

Can anyone suggest me how to investigate this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the method correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your view controller is either set as the window's rootViewController, or it is contained within a container view controller that is set as that.

Your issue will be that it is not receiving the window notification which is passed to the root view controller, and then further down to each of its children, and then down to their children etc.

If you have made your own custom container view controllers, ensure they all forward the message on to their children appropriately. Somewhere in that chain is a break.